# how to find the greatest value of multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

eg I have several arrays like this:

```
$data1 = array(80, 'P3');
$data2 = array(55, 'P3');
$data3 = array(90, 'P3');
```

how to find the greatest value of some of the array?
help me please, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3);
sort($x);
$highest = array_pop($x);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `sort($x);` not `$sort($x)`.